# React - change this.state onClick rendered with array.map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and JavaScript.

I have a Menu component which renders an animation `onClick` and then redirects the app to another route, `/coffee`.

I would like to pass the value which was clicked (selected) to function `this.gotoCoffee` and update `this.state.select`, but I don't know how, since I am mapping all items in `this.state.coffees` in the same `onClick` event.

How do I do this and update `this.state.select` to the clicked value?

My code:

```
class Menus extends Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        coffees:[],
        select: '',      
        isLoading: false,
        redirect: false
    };
  };
  gotoCoffee = () => {
    this.setState({isLoading:true})
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.setState({isLoading:false,redirect:true})
    },5000)
  }

  renderCoffee = () => {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return (<Redirect to={`/coffee/${this.state.select}`} />)
    }
  }

  render(){
    const data = this.state.coffees;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="title is-1"><font color="#C86428">Menu</font></h1>
        <hr/><br/>
        {data.map(c => 
          <span key={c}>
            <div>
               {this.state.isLoading && <Brewing />}
               {this.renderCoffee()}
              <div onClick={() => this.gotoCoffee()} 
                  <strong><font color="#C86428">{c}</font></strong></div>
            </div>
          </span>)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Menus);
```

---

I have tried passing the value like so:

```
  gotoCoffee = (e) => {
    this.setState({isLoading:true,select:e})
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.setState({isLoading:false,redirect:true})
    },5000) 
    console.log(this.state.select)
  }
```

an like so:

```
<div onClick={(c) => this.gotoCoffee(c)}
```

or so:

```
<div onClick={(event => this.gotoCoffee(event.target.value}
```

but `console.log(this.state.select)` shows me '`undefined`' for both tries.

It appears that I'm passing the `Class` with 'c'.

browser shows me precisely that on the uri at redirect:

`http://localhost/coffee/[object%20Object]`

---

Now if I pass mapped 'c' to `{this.renderCoffee(c)}`, which not an `onClick` event, I manage to pass the array items.

But I need to pass not the object, but the clicked value 'c' to `this.gotoCoffee(c)`, and THEN update `this.state.select`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It looks like you can just pass `c` as an argument to `this.gotoCoffee()`, unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass `index` of element to `gotoCoffee` with closure in `render`. Then in `gotoCoffee`, just access that element as `this.state.coffees[index]`.

```
gotoCoffee = (index) => {
    this.setState({isLoading:true, select: this.state.coffees[index]})
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.setState({isLoading:false,redirect:true})
    },5000)
  }

  render(){
    const data = this.state.coffees;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="title is-1"><font color="#C86428">Menu</font></h1>
        <hr/><br/>
        {data.map((c, index) => 
          <span key={c}>
            <div>
               {this.state.isLoading && <Brewing />}
               {this.renderCoffee()}
              <div onClick={() => this.gotoCoffee(index)} 
                  <strong><font color="#C86428">{c}</font></strong></div>
            </div>
          </span>)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

so based off your code you could do it a couple of ways.

`onClick=(event) => this.gotoCoffee(event.target.value)`

This looks like the approach you want.

`onClick=() => this.gotoCoffee(c)`

`c` would be related to your item in the array.

Comment: thank you, but could you please add `this.setState({select:c})`, or how it would be done, to your answer?

Answer (score 4):

All the answers look alright and working for you and  it's  obvious you made a mistake by not passing the correct value in click handler. But since you're new in this era I thought it's better to change your implementation this way:

- It's not necessary use constructor at all and you can declare a state property with initial values:

  ```
  class Menus extends Component{
      state= {
          /* state properties */
      };
  }
  ```
- When you declare functions in render method it always creates a new one each rendering which has some cost and is not optimized. It's better if you use currying:

  ```
  handleClick = selected => () => { /* handle click */ }
  render () {
      // ...
      coffees.map( coffee =>
          // ...
           <div onClick={ this.handleClick(coffee) }>
          // ...
  }
  ```
- You can redirect with `history.replace` since you wrapped your component with `withRouter`and that's helpful here cause you redirecting on click and get rid of `renderCoffee` method:

  ```
  handleClick = selected => () => 
      this.setState(
          { isLoading: true},
          () => setTimeout(
              () => {
                  const { history } = this.props;
                  this.setState({ isLoading: false });
                  history.replace(`/${coffee}`);
              }
              , 5000)
      );
  ```

Since `Redirect` replaces route and I think you want normal page change not replacing I  suggest using `history.push` instead.

Comment: thank you for your answer. actually I need the constructor. This is not the full component code. I need to use `this.props` elsewhere. +1 for the tip on `history.replace()`, though. will think about using it instead of `<Redirect>`.

Comment: @data_garden glad to hear it's  helpful. Try to use `componentDidMount` if possible

Comment: I guess your state declaration has a little issue `state: {`, as a class properties, it should be like `state = {`. thanks for your answer. I leave an upvote.

Comment: @AmerllicA You are right. such errors are not noticeable unless you have either error check on or a pair of hawk eyes ;)

Answer (score 0):

You've actually almost got it in your question. I'm betting the reason your state is undefined is due to the short lived nature of `event`. `setState` is an asynchronous action and does not always occur immediately. By passing the event off directly and allowing the function to proceed as normal, the event is released before state can be set. My advice would be to update your `gotoCoffee` function to this:

```
 gotoCoffee = (e) => {
    const selectedCoffee = e.target.value
    this.setState({isLoading:true,select:selectedCoffee},() => 
     {console.log(this.state.select})
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.setState({isLoading:false,redirect:true})
    },5000) 
  }
```

Note that I moved your console.log line to a callback function within setState so that it's not triggered until AFTER state has updated. Any time you are using a class component and need to do something immediately after updating state, use the callback function.